# No Clipboard Data On Document Bind with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to intercept and control all user input that goes onto the screen, so I've written this directive:

```
myApp.directive('keypressEvents', function($document, $rootScope, $location, $browser) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

            $document.bind('keydown keypress', function(e) {
                console.log(e.originalEvent.clipboardData);
                e.preventDefault();
                $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);
            });

    };
});
```

And I place the directive on the  tag. The problem I am having is the clipboard data is empty. There is no e.originalEvent.clipboardData, e.clipboardData or window.clipboardData.

My question is why is this being removed or not accessible?

Comment: can you create fiddle for this

Comment: You could start listen `document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){...});` instead of `$document.bind('keydown keypress', function(e) {...}`